# How do I use the add_query_arg function in a template tag like previous_post_link?

Tags: theme-development, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I am trying to change the output of the `previous_post_link` and the `next_post_link` and basically add a query argument to them. The documentation just mentions that you can use the `%link` placeholder that is basically replaced by `<a href="`... the whole shebang. This does not help me, since I can't just add the query argument using simple concatenation.

Even if there is no direct way to actually use `add_query_arg` on the template tag, is there at least some kind of documentation regarding the placeholders that are available to me (besides `%link`)? If it **is** possible to do that and I have just the `href` value part available to me, I could just build my own markup with it.

I did an extensive google search on the subject and even checked the implementation of `previous_post_link` and `next_post_link` in `wp-includes/link-template.php`, but just the post is returned there (no mention to how this thing is themed at all).

Thanks in advance for any insight that you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`previous_post_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/previous_post_link/) and its sibling are pretty simple functions, so there's not a lot to play with if you really want to use these (if you're building a plugin and do not want to touch the theme, making you need a filter which isn't there).

However, since you're talking about templates, I'm guessing that you're building a theme. That gives you another option, namely building your own previous/next post link. The instrument for this is [`get_adjacent_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post).

That function will simply give you the previous/next post as an object, leaving you all posibilities to change the permalink with `add_query_arg` and then build your html around it.

Comment: I will upvote as soon as I have enough reputation. Thanks a lot, this did the trick. I actually saw that this is the function that previous_post_link is calling internally in the link-template.php file but for some reason I didn't think to try it directly. Thanks again!

Comment: Sometimes things are easier than you think ;-)